# IOS App to react to IFTTT notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, ifttt

I am trying to find a way from my IOS App (written in Swift) to react to an IFFT notification.  I am using static and dynamic notifications in my code and this part is working (with a test notification).  The issue is my app is not responding to or seeing the IFFFT notifications.  The notification is showing up on my iPhone under normal IOS notifications (outside my App).  Maybe this is easy and I am just missing something or maybe not possible at all?

The notification code is very simple, I am just looking for the IFTTT Event Name as my Notification Category Name (is this the problem?) in Interface.Storyboard but my function:

```
 override func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification, withCompletion completionHandler: @escaping (WKUserNotificationInterfaceType) -> Swift.Void)
```

is never getting called.

The app I am writing is to ask my Amazon Alexa to trigger something on my custom device.  I wrote an Alex Skill that sends a message to the Webhook service and this triggers the IFTTT IOS notification.   Everything is working except for my APP not seeing the notification.  Is there a more straightforward way to implement what I am trying to do?

This is just for my own project and not looking to publish this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you sending the notification? Remote notifications are sent to a specific app. Your app cannot receive notifications that are sent to the IFTTT app, if that is what you are trying to do.